# Making the Android gallery view look nicer

Tags: android, gallery

Any ideas of how to make tis galley view look nicer? as its not the best looking at the moment. Any help would be much appreciated and it can be anything from sizing to borders and even layout :)

The .xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Gallery>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My Activity:

```
package kevin.erica.box;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class App2Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);
    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        public void onItemClick(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
            imageview.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);


        }
    });
}

public Integer[] mImageIds = {
        R.drawable.lemon,
        R.drawable.kevin,
        R.drawable.mirror
};
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
int mGalleryItemBackground;
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
    mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
            R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
    a.recycle();
}
public int getCount() {
    return mImageIds.length;
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
    i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
    return i;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the whole shape of Gallery by using coverflow one ,if you want or stack with yours and adjaust it .

check this link :

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html

hope this help

Comment: It does kinda help but im finding this really hard to implement